# работа в html и css

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста,
как в слове WHITE в каждой букве установить разную жирность.

Рисунок ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать так:

```html
<p>
  <span style='font-weight: 900; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);'>W</span>
  <span style='font-weight: 700; color: rgb(43, 43, 43);'>H</span>
  <span style='font-weight: 500; color: rgb(104, 104, 104);'>I</span>
  <span style='font-weight: 400; color: rgb(165, 165, 165);'>T</span>
  <span style='font-weight: 100; color: rgb(201, 201, 201);'>E</span>
</p>
```

там все же больше идет эффект из за разницы цвета у букв, а не из за жирности шрифта

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Ира, если ответ вам полезен и решает ваш вопрос, то можете отметить его, нажав соответствующую кнопку слева от него ))

Comment: Вот кстати именно цвет и не нужно было делать, вместо него лучше использовать `opacity`, чтобы текст был более универсальным (то есть работал в большем кол-ве кейсов).

Answer (score 4):

```css
p {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 0, #cecece 80%, #fff 100%);
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>IMAGE</p>
```